# How to make the discord oauth2 join yourself to a discord server

Tags: discord.js

I'm interested about making a discord oauth2 that invites u to a discord server but without opening the invitation urself, it just join you simply

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the user must confirm the connection to the server.